# How to Cut Everything except UTF-8 Encoding in Notepad++

Tags: regex, utf-8, notepad++

I have a text file similar to the following:

```
<a style="color:#414146;" onclick="return trackOutboundLink(true,'Current Affair Page','question widget',' question click');" href="https://onlinetyari.com/hindi/question-bank/question-sentral-soyal-saileniti-i17677.html">
                                                सेण्ट्रल सोयल सैलेनिटी रिसर्च इंस्टीट्यूट (CSSRI) हरियाणा के किस जिले में स्थित 
हैं ?                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="show-optipns light">
                                                <a class="s_option" id="options_17677" onclick="showOption('17677','1')" style="text-align:right">Show Options</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="question_17677" class="question_info" name="question_info">
                                                <div id="op_1_17677" class="col-sm-6 question-option form-group cursor-pointer" onclick="showAnswer('17677',1,1)" style="float:none">
                                                    <div class="input-group regular">
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon">A</span>
                                                        <div id="checkbox1_17677" type="text" class="form-control checkbox_data" id="inputGroupSuccess3" aria-describedby="inputGroupSuccess3Status">
                                                            करनाल में                                                            <span id="chk-tick1-17677"></span>
                                                            <span id="inputGroupSuccess3Status" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="op_2_17677" class="col-sm-6 question-option form-group cursor-pointer" onclick="showAnswer('17677',2,1)" style="float:none">
                                                    <div class="input-group regular">
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon">B</span>
                                                        <div id="checkbox2_17677" type="text" class="form-control checkbox_data" id="inputGroupSuccess3" aria-describedby="inputGroupSuccess3Status">
                                                            महेन्द्रगढ़ में
```

I want to remove everything except **Hindi** words, so my file remains only:

सेण्ट्रल सोयल सैलेनिटी रिसर्च इंस्टीट्यूट हरियाणा के किस जिले में स्थित 
हैं ?          करनाल में            महेन्द्रगढ़ में

Is this possible with regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove everything that matches this regex:

```
[^[:unicode:]]+
```

If you want to preserve spaces, then remove everything that matches this regex instead:

```
[^[:unicode:]\s]+
```

Then, if you want to condense all the spacing down to single spaces, do a search for:

```
\s+
```

And replace it with a single space. Here is what that result looks like:

सेण्ट्रल सोयल सैलेनिटी रिसर्च इंस्टीट्यूट हरियाणा के किस जिले में स्थित हैं करनाल में महेन्द्रगढ़ में

Comment: how to get line break and space at same time, i am getting  all  output in one line without space.